# Cannot see the openFileDialog and saveFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, filedialog

I am creating a windows form with the openFileDialog and the showFileDialog icons. But when I run the form, I do not see the options in the top left corner.
Is there some properties that I need to change to visible or something?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

These Dialog are not shown unless you perform any action (either clicking a save button or open file Button)
what you need to do create a button and then handle its click event
something like this.

```
  this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

and then in this event, you can invoke your dialog

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName; // this is the selected file
    }
}
```